# 2 batch string questions

Tags: string, batch-file

1) Is there any built-in which can tell me if a variable's contents contain only uppercase letters?

2) is there any way to see if a variable contains a string? For example, I'd like to see if the variable %PATH% contains Ruby.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For part 1, `findstr` is the answer. You can just use the regex feature along with `errorlevel`:

```
> set xxokay=ABC
> set xxbad=AB1C
> echo %xxokay%|findstr /r "^[A-Z]*$" >nul:
> echo %errorlevel%
0
> echo %xxbad%|findstr /r "^[A-Z]*$" >nul:
> echo %errorlevel%
1
```

It's important in this case that you do *not* have a space between the `echo %xxokay%` and the pipe character `|`, since that will result in a space being output which is not one of your acceptable characters.

---

For part 2, `findstr` is also the answer (`/i` is ignore case which may be what you want - leave it off if case must match):

```
> set xxruby=somewhere;c:\ruby;somewhere_else
> set xxnoruby=somewhere;somewhere_else
> echo %xxruby%|findstr /i ruby >nul:
> echo %errorlevel%
0
> echo %xxnoruby%|findstr /i ruby >nul:
> echo %errorlevel%
1
```

You can then use:

```
if %errorlevel%==1 goto :label
```

to change the behaviour of your script in both cases.

For example, the code segment for the ruby check could be something like:

```
:ruby_check
    echo %yourvar%|findstr /i ruby >nul:
    if %errorlevel%==1 goto :ruby_check_not_found
:ruby_check_found
    :: ruby was found
    goto :ruby_check_end
:ruby_check_not_found:
    :: ruby was NOT found
:ruby_check_end
```

Answer (score 1):

this is not a batch solution (cmd.exe), but an easier alternative using vbscript, which by default is already installed on your system.

```
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
var=objArgs(0)
check=var
If check=UCase(var) Then
  WScript.Echo "String contains all uppercase"
Else
  WScript.Echo "String doesn't contain all uppercase"
End If
' to check string contains substring
mystring="This is my ruby string"
check="ruby"
If InStr(mystring,check)>0 Then
    WScript.Echo "string contains ruby"
End If
```

save the file as `myscript.vbs` and run it like this

```
C:\test>cscript //nologo myscript.vbs abC
String doesn't contain all uppercase
string contains ruby

C:\test>cscript //nologo myscript.vbs ABCD
String contains all uppercase
string contains ruby
```

using batch(cmd.exe) for string manipulation is the last thing you would want to do, unless you are absolutely restricted. Otherwise, use the more appropriate tool for the job.