# How can I check whether with ASP.NET 4 is registered to run in IIS 7.5?

Tags: iis-7.5, asp.net-4.0

How can I check whether with ASP.NET 4 is registered to run in IIS 7.5?

There must be some way to determine this for sure, other than running

```
aspnet_regiis -i
```

from within the framework's folder.

I don't need to check this programmatically, just via IIS Manager or the commend line. I have an .NET page that is returing a 500 error, which I have determined could be due to ASP.NET 4 not being registered with IIS.

However, I want to be certain before I make changes to the server configuration.

Comment: are you wanting to do this progromatically?   like something in an installer?

Comment: go in to the app pool for that website (or any site on the server) and see what the frameworks are set to.  You can click on any of them and if 4.0 is registered to IIS then it should be a choice in the drop down list.

Comment: I can select 4.0 However, doing so throws a 500 error, where selecting 2.0 does not, and renders the page.

Comment: stupid question but was the app compiled in 4.0?   I've seen this when the app pool was set to 2.0 but the app was compiled in 4.0.

Comment: you can also try changing from integrated to classic or vice versa

Comment: @Brian, do you know any programatic solution? Would be very handy...

Comment: Don't know one off the top of my head.  you can run aspnet_regiis -lk and this will show you what framework is tied to each site.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `aspnet_regiis` with parameter `-lv`, i.e.:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -lv
```

This will give you the following output:

```
Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.34209
Administration utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
2.0.50727.0             C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll
4.0.30319.0             C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll
4.0.30319.0             C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll
```

In this example, you can see that `v4.0.30319.0`, 32 and 64 bit dll's, are installed.
To install the latest version, for example after applying a .NET Framework update, use

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -iru
```

**Note:** On **64 bit IIS servers,** you need to use **"Framework64"** instead of "Framework" in the paths above. Strangely, I found on some servers with 64 bit "Framework" in the path worked, on others I had to use "Framework64" - simply try it out. If the registration does not work, run it again with "Framework64" in the path, it does not harm. In one case, I had to change the path using `cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework`, then I typed `aspnet_regiis -iru` to make it finally work.

---

You mentioned that you need to check it programmatically: The command above can be used in a batch file, and via [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634959/2-batch-string-questions) you can find the string `"4.0.30319.0"` in the output (provided you're using "aspnet_regiis -lv > outputfile.txt" to write the output into a text file).

Answer (score -1):

```
appcmd list config /section:globalModules /text:[name='ManagedEngine'].image
```

Comment: -1: I've got ASP.NET 4.0 correctly configured, and this only shows ASP.NET v2.0.